# Can't get multiple rows using filter in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

First off, brand new to R. Here is the dataframe I am working with:
[image]

I am trying to filter OUT the first row and keep the rest. I have tried using the code shown here:

```
>finaldata[finaldata$Date == '2010',]
```

Obviously, it is doing the opposite of what I want, and only showing the first row. This made sense to me after using it, but how can I go the other way, ridding the first row while keeping the rest in a data frame?

Tried various iterations of filter() and other recommendations found online.

Comment: Try `finaldata[finaldata$Date != '2010',]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out first row you can use finaldata = finaldata [-1,]